# Correlating how a user feels about the website and the number of purchases

Tags: regression, correlation, survey, ordinal-data

TLDR - Can we use regression to correlate survey response (ordinal) to user actions (continuous)?

Say we want to know if improvements to the checkout process of a website lead to more purchases. We've run an A/B experiment and results are good (new design had more purchases!) but we want to dive a little deeper into the user experience and run a likert survey on how users perceived the changes. We ask, "On a scale of 1-5 was the new design easier to use?" And we bucket the responses as 1 & 2 being Worse, 3 being Neutral and 4 & 5 being Better.

Would it be valid to use regression to correlate these responses to the number of purchases, with interpretation being something along the lines of, "Users who thought the checkout process was easier to use purchased x more widgets on average?" My concern is that there are tons of exogenous variables besides user perception that affect the number of purchases, and whether that means the survey data should even be used like this.

Or perhaps have purchases be the independent variable and response be the dependent via ordinal regression? Then saying, "More purchases are correlated with better perception of checkout process."

Comment: I can see difficulties with the analysis you propose. First off, how are you going to do this survey? You'll have to find users who used the old website and the new website, then gather responses. You'll have no way of knowing that the users who self-select to respond to the survey are representative of all your users. (But if you could do it, you can also do a more powerful paired analysis by comparing pre and post purchases.)